# Pre 1962 YA book where two boys are miniaturized

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

There was a book fair in my grade school in Philadelphia  - we moved away in November 1961 so it was before then.

I saw the book cover with a picture of two boys who had obviously been miniaturized somehow.  And maybe a read the blurb about the book.  But I didn't buy it and don't remember the title or author.

Comment: How did you know they'd been miniaturized?  Presumably they were shown against something that gave them scale; what?  Blades of grass?  Insects?  Desk supplies?  Laboratory supplies?

Comment: @M.A.Golding unless you have a little more detail this will be very hard to pin down. You can look up a list of 1950's and earlier SF on wikipedia and see if any of the book covers look familiar. A quick search just now turned up this one which vaguely fits what you describe... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Flight_to_the_Mushroom_Planet

Comment: @Skyjack  I think that I read it, and the boys are not shrunken, the mushrooms are huge.

Comment: This might be "The Boys Who Vanished" by John F. Carson.